# Show status of each thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

My application runs some threads and every thread does something.
I want that each thread shows its status in a list box.

So, how a thread can identify itself (by using thread ID or something else) and set its status into a `List`?

Comment: What do you mean by thread status?

Comment: @Falanwe for example how much time remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thread has an id. You can access it with

```
Thread t;
int id = t.ManagedThreadId;
```

To update a global datastructure with some state i would use a dictionary and use the id as the key. Be aware of locking the access of that data structure:

```
Dictionary<int, SomeStateClass> threadStates = new Dictionary<int, SomeStateClass>();

public void updateThreadState(int id, SomeStateClass newState) {
    lock (threadStates) {
        threadStates[id] = newState;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can identify managed threads with [Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx). And remember to [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) calls to your listbox (or use [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) in case you are using WPF), as threads other then UI thread can not access it directly.

Comment: Is it needed to invoke calls if I fill data to a List and set the datasource of a ListBox to it?

Comment: @Mahdi: yes you need an invoke, by the way, as you're going to act on main thread from the secondary one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Invoke` with delegates. Each thread would then be responsible for updating the ListBoxItem it owns.

Answer (score 1):

You could just keep a collection (Array, List, whatever you want) of the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) you want to monitor. The thread class exposes many properties you may want, including the ThreadState property. From there it is easy to display the informations you want.

This way your working threads will not have to worry about notifying their status.